# how to score 100 on google PageSpeed with google charts?

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization, pagespeed

I am trying, to score 100, with google chart, on [Google PageSpeed Analyzer](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/), but keep getting "Minifying https://www.google.com/…at+en,default+en,ui+en,corechart+en.I.js could save 1.7KiB (1% reduction) after compression." how can I get full score on this? TIA
Here is my basic sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
<body><div id="myChart"></div></body></html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function(){pie();}

    google.load('visualization','1.0',{'packages':['corechart']});
    function pie(){
        var data=new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string','Type');
        data.addColumn('number','Percentage');
        data.addRows([['WE',99],['THEM',1]]);

        var options={'width':500,'height':400,'is3D':true,'chartArea':{left:25,top:25,width:"100%",height:"100%"}};

        var chart=new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('myChart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be getting that message - the Visualization API code (which is what that link points to) is already minified.

Comment: I am totally agree with you, but I got that message just as the code I posted after minified the javascript portion. I don't know if the problem is from Visualization end, my end, or the PageSpeed end. If it is from my end, I really like to know how to correct that. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: It's either a problem with PageSpeed incorrectly identifying opportunities to save space by minifying, or the Visualization API code isn't fully minified (unlikely).

Answer (score 1):

Google Page Speed Analyzer is detecting that you have resources that can be minified - in this case your javascript file.  Code minification is a simple process.  Just run your code through a code minifer - it will eliminate any whitespace that's unnecessary for the code to run properly.  Doing this will decrease the file size of the resource, and in turn speed up the user's download.

Take a look at the Google Page Speed Analyzer's docs for suggested code minfiers:

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/MinifyResources

Comment: Not sure if your suggestions are directly related to my problem. I passed the "Enable compression" rule, but not the "Minify JavaScript" rule. Would configure HTTP compression help me pass the "Minify JavaScript" rule? if so, I should start to mess around with that. TIA

Comment: No, actually it's not related at all.  Sorry, long day at work - to minify code, just search online for a javascript minifyer.  It just compresses all the code down to as little whitespace as possible while still making it valid code.

Comment: @xam - edited to answer the question that you were ACTUALLY asking :D

Comment: I did all the minify that I could on javascript, but still, I could not pass the "Minify JavaScript" rule. I know the code above could be minify, but if I posted the minified version of the javascript above, people wouldn't understand what I was trying to do. In other words, even I minify the above code, I still could not pass the "Minify JavaScript" rule. Thanks for trying to answer the question.

Comment: Perhaps if you check carefully on the minifying suggestion given by PageSpeed, It suggested to minify "https://www.google.com/…at+en,default+en,ui+en,corechart+en.I.js", which was not called anywhere in my code. It is a brick wall to me and don't know how to proceed. TIA

Comment: Are there any other scripts being called by your markup besides the two in the markup you posted?

Comment: no, this is the entire code. I think the call was made from Google Charts API itself. Thanks again.